# Why is this json example an object is parsed as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this JSON code :

```
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "-1": {
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "StackOverflow",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I parsed it into a JSON object :

```
data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Why to access the object `-1` I must do `data.query.pages[-1]` not data.query.pages.-1. In this example `pages` is not an array but an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an array, it's an object.  Both `object["name"]` and `object.name` are identical ways of accessing a property called `name` on the given object.

You cannot access an object property with `object.-1`, simply because that's a syntax error, the same way you can't use `object.+1` or `object.[1` or `object./1`. They're all valid names for a property of an object, but they're syntactically invalid when using `object.propertyName` syntax.

The other caveat is that you cannot have property names which are integers. Setting or getting `object[-1]` is identical to `object["-1"]` as the property name is converted to a string. It *would* be identical to accessing `object.-1` if that were valid syntax.

Comment: [this is a good resource](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#properties), though i suppose it doesn't mention anything about numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `data.query.pages.-1` for the same reason you can't do `var -1;`: `-1` is not a valid identifier.

But that's not a problem.

```
foo.bar       // Access member bar of object foo
```

is just a shortcut for

```
foo["bar"]    // Access member bar of object foo
```

so you can do

```
data.query.pages["-1"]
```

You could even do

```
data["query"]["pages"]["-1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bracket notation has nothing to with arrays, it's just another way to access *properties*. In fact, the reason why we can only use bracket notation for arrays is because of the evaluation rules: To use dot notation, the property name must be a valid [**identifier name**](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6).

Or simply put:

> You can only use dot notation if the property name would be a **valid variable name or a reserved word**.

And `-1` doesn't fall in that category (you can't do `var -1 = 'foo';` for example).

---

Examples for invalid identifier names:

- `0foo`, `-foo`, `&bar`
  anything that doesn't start with a letter, `_` or `$`
- `foo-bar`, `foo+bar`, `foo bar`
  anything that contains something that is not a letter, a digit, `_` or `$` (or fall into specific unicode ranges, see the spec).

However, using reserved words is possible, even though they can't be used as variables:

```
foo.if // valid
var if = 42; // invalid
```